# Sorted Dictionary sorted on value in C# (LRU cache)

Tags: c#, algorithm, caching, collections

I want to implement an **`LRU cache`** , where least recently used elements will be evicted asynchronously . My current idea is to use a `Dictionary` to store the `<key,value>` pairs , and to keep track of the times of accesses of the objects, to keep a `SortedDictionary <key, timestamp>`. The idea is for the async thread to get the LRU items from the `SortedDictionary` and remove from the cache . But for this to work, `SortedDictionary` needs to sort by value, which it does not.

I could have used a separate `SortedList` instead of the `SortedDictionary` for keeping the {key and timestamp} sorted on the timestamp , but then I'll have to do a "linear" lookup for finding the key from the list (when I have to UPDATE the timestamp, when the same key is accessed again) - I am looking for a better than linear way if possible. Can someone share ideas to deal with this problem?

So, my problem boils down to this:

I've to lookup keys in <= logn time for UPDATING the timestamp while at the same time able to get the keys sorted based on the timestamp .

One way thought of was to keep a `SortedDictionary` of `<{key,timestamp},null>` which orders the keys based on the timestamp part of {key,timestamp} . While this is fine , the problem is `hashcode()` will just have to return key.hashcode() (for lookup while updating timestamp) , while `equals()` should also use timestamp . So , `equals()` and `hashcode()` are in conflict , so felt that this is not a good idea ...

Comment: In other words, you want the SortedDic to act like priority queue where priority is defined by timestamp? What is wrong with SortedDictionary <timestamp, key> ? And BTW it is not O(1) it's O(logn) - it's probably implemented as a Red-Black tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should do is keep two dictionaries, one sorted by time and one by keys.

Remember that dictionaries are only holding references to your actual objects, so which dictionary you use to update the object doesn't matter.

To update the object create a function that will update both the dictionaries

```
var oldObj = keyedObject[key];
timedObjects.Remove(oldObj.LastUpdateTime);
timedObjects.Add(myUpdatedObject.LastUpdateTime,myUpdatedObject);
keyedObject[key] = myUpdatedObject;
```

Now you have track of the same object by both time and key.

I am keeping only one reference to an object in `timedObjects`. This helps while removing.

You can keep trimming your timedObjects dictionary as required.

Ofcource, while trimming you must bear in mind that there is another dictionary `keyedObject` that has reference to the same object. Merely calling `Remove` will not be enough.

Your remove code will have to be like this:

```
removeObject = timedObjects[timeToRemove];
timedObjects.Remove(timeToRemove);
keyedObject.Remove(removeObject.key);
```

*timeToRemove will mostly come from a for loop, where you decide which object to remove*

Comment: +1, two dictionaries.  Note that red-black trees are rather slow, but they give pretty consistent performance.  For speed, a treap is better, but treaps' operation durations have a high standard deviation.

Comment: good idea .. but , i dont think there is a need to compute timeToRemove . the element to remove (the one with the least timestamp , or the first one in the timedObjects sortedmap ) could be  found by timedObjects.first . Rite ?

Comment: Yes, that would work if you were removing only one object at a time. But you mentioned wanting to use a separate thread to remove items. This means your timedObject dictionary may grow larger than the size you want for the LRU, and you will have to remove more than one item.

Answer (score 1):

here is the implementation of the LRU Cache in c#. efficient O(1), but not thread safe;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cache = new LruCache(3);
        cache.Put(1, 1);
        cache.Put(2, 2);
        Console.WriteLine(cache.Get(1));       // returns 1
        cache.Put(3, 3);    // evicts key 2
        Console.WriteLine(cache.Get(2));       // returns -1 (not found)
        cache.Put(4, 4);    // evicts key 1
        Console.WriteLine(cache.Get(1));       // returns -1 (not found)
        Console.WriteLine(cache.Get(3));       // returns 3
        Console.WriteLine(cache.Get(4));       // returns 4     

    }

    public class DoubleLinkedList
    {
        public int key;
        public int value;
        public DoubleLinkedList next;
        public DoubleLinkedList prev;
        public DoubleLinkedList(int k, int v)
        {
            key = k;
            value = v;
        }
    }

    public class LruCache
    {
        private int size;
        private int capacity;
        private Dictionary<int, DoubleLinkedList> map;
        private DoubleLinkedList head;
        private DoubleLinkedList tail;
        public LruCache(int cap)
        {
            capacity = cap;
            map = new Dictionary<int, DoubleLinkedList>();
            head = new DoubleLinkedList(0, 0);
            tail = new DoubleLinkedList(0, 0);
            head.next = tail;
            tail.prev = head;
        }

        public int Get(int key)
        {
            if (map.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                if (tail.prev.key != key)
                {
                    var node = map[key];
                    RemoveNode(node);
                    AddToEnd(node);
                }
                return map[key].value;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        private void AddToEnd(DoubleLinkedList node)
        {
            var beforeTail = tail.prev;
            node.prev = beforeTail;
            beforeTail.next = node;
            tail.prev = node;
            node.next = tail;
        }

        private void RemoveNode(DoubleLinkedList node)
        {
            var before = node.prev;
            before.next = node.next;
            node.next.prev = before;
        }

        public void Put(int key, int value)
        {
            if (map.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                map[key].value = value;
                var node = map[key];
                RemoveNode(node);
                AddToEnd(node);
            }
            else
            {
                size++;
                if (size > capacity)
                {
                    var node = head.next;
                    RemoveNode(node);
                    map.Remove(node.key);
                    size--;
                }

                var newNode = new DoubleLinkedList(key, value);
                AddToEnd(newNode);
                map.Add(key, newNode);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of map you're looking for is (at least in Java) called a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

From the javadoc:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (*insertion-order*).
>
> A special constructor is provided to create a linked hash map whose
>   order of iteration is the order in which its entries were last
>   accessed, from least-recently accessed to most-recently
>   (*access-order*). This kind of map is **well-suited to building LRU
>   caches**.

[Source for `LinkedHashMap` from the OpenJDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java)

AFAIK, there are no existing implementations of a `LinkedHashMap` in C#. That being said, it shouldn't be terribly difficult to write one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sorteddictionary, write your own linked list, and have the Dictionary point to its nodes as values. It will be always sorted by timestamp, updating timestamp and removing the least resently used element will be O(1).